# QGIS Layers not lining up with same CRS projections

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, layers

I've been working with Boston parcel and transit shapefiles downloaded directly from either the city website or MassGIS data center and can't figure out why the shapefiles are not lining up. I have 'on the fly' enabled and have set the project CRS to WGS 84 UTM19N as well as set each individual layer CRS to the same but the layers aren't layering. I'm working in QGIS 2.18.2 on a Mac.

The links to the shapefiles are as follows.
**Parcel:** http://bostonopendata-boston.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/f3d274161b4a47aa9acf48d0d04cd5d4_0?mapSize=map-maximize&geometry=-71.923%2C41.978%2C-70.221%2C42.465
**Transit:** http://www.mass.gov/anf/research-and-tech/it-serv-and-support/application-serv/office-of-geographic-information-massgis/datalayers/mbta.html

Comment: don't set the layer CRS unless you know what it should be and are sure you know what you are doing

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just tried a new project file without changing layer CRS' and only having 'on the fly' project projection enabled.  Still the layers don't align between the transit and the parcels.

Comment: the first one is epsg;4326 and the second is epsg:3585 (Mass State Plane M)

Comment: Just change the layer CRS back and it worked perfectly letting the 'on the fly' do its thing.  Thank you!